# UPDATE ON DUPLICATE on a repeating item

Tags: mysql

I have a query that updates the db using EVENT SCHEDULER. Its supposed to update data once a day. My issue is that I can't get it to update if the record exists unless I create UNIQUE INDEX which I can't do since the domain repeats for each month.

```
INSERT INTO f_s.s_d_s_tab(month,count_per_month,updated)
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(`FE`,'%m') AS Month, COUNT(FE) AS FirstCount, domain
FROM rets
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`FE`,'%m'), domain
ORDER BY domain, Month ASC
) a
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count_per_month = a.FirstCount, updated = NOW();
```

records show like so

```
Domain    Month    coun_per_month
dom1       01        50
dom1       02        90
dom1       03        34
dom2       01        12
dom2       02        99
dom2       03        80
```

etc....

what can I do to make it insert new domains but update old ones.

Comment: `UNIQUE(Domain, Month)`?

Comment: I would use ` ... UPDATE count_per_month = VALUES(count_per_month) ... ` to reference the value that would have been inserted. The columns from your SELECT don't seem to "line up" with the column names on the INSERT.  (Looks like `domain` is being put into the `updated` column.

Answer (score 2):

> My issue is that I can't get it to update if the record exists unless I create UNIQUE INDEX which I can't do since the domain repeats for each month.

Sure you can - make a [multi-column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) unique index, on Domain and Month.

Comment: so basically if domain and month are unique it will insert otherwise it will update?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like the columns from your SELECT list "line up" with the columns in the INSERT list.

```
INSERT INTO f_s.s_d_s_tab(domain, month, count_per_month, updated)
SELECT a.*
  FROM (
         SELECT r.domain                 AS domain
              , DATE_FORMAT(r.`FE`,'%m') AS month
              , COUNT(r.FE)              AS count_per_month
              , NOW()                    AS updated
           FROM rets r
          GROUP
             BY DATE_FORMAT(r.`FE`,'%m')
              , r.domain
          ORDER BY r.domain ASC, r.month ASC
       ) a
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE count_per_month = VALUES(count_per_month)
     , updated         = VALUES(updated)
```

To generate a "duplicate key" condition to get the UPDATE action, you'll need a UNIQUE constraint (or PRIMARY KEY) defined `ON f_s.s_d_s_tab (domain, month)`.